# How to handle a unit conversion property in ASP.Net Core MVC model?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

Let's say you have a model property like this:

```
[Display(Name = "Length (ft)"]
public double LengthFt {get; set;}
```

Now you want another property that has length in meters that will be used in your input and output forms:

```
[Display(Name = "Length (m)"]
[NotMapped]
public double LengthMeters
{
    get => LengthFt * 0.3048;
    set => LengthFt = value / 0.2048;
}
```

Should this work? Mine (a much more complex example than this) is working on the "get" portion (returning LengthMeters correctly when LengthFt is set), and is working on the Create form (the standard Create view from ASP.Net Core MVC), but is not working on the Edit. The Edit form shows the correct initial value, but when I overwrite it and click "Save", both fields are now 0. It's like the Edit isn't seeing the change to the NotMapped element, but the Create action does.

Is there a more elegant way to handle these types of transformations?

Comment: Are you sure the model binding to LengthMeters is actually working?  Can you post your view model and controller action method code.  It looks like the value being set from the edit form is always zero.  But I don't understand why you're even setting LengthMeters when you only have to set LengthFt to calculate LengthMeters.

Comment: We have a whole library of calculations that accept a value in SCFH (standard cubic feet per hour) and the customer decided that they always want to enter and see results in MCFH (thousands of cubic feet per hour). So it’s simply a divide/multiply by one thousand, but code wise, it was easier to leave all the other model references (and database entries) in SCFH but translate it at the UI level. But the binding issue with Editting made me wonder if there is a flaw in my reasoning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "LengthMeters" was omitted from the Bind command on the Edit method in the controller. When properly bound, this technique seems to work fine.

Still wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this, but it seems to be working now.